# Perform diff% on 2 different matrices

Tags: powerbi, dax

I really need help here.
My user illustrated what they wanted on Excel. And I have tried doing like that on Power BI using matrix viz. Here are examples of my data.

They are matrices with summarized data **with different point of time**

**As of 7 Sep 2022**

```
         |      GROUP A     |Sub total  |       GROUP B     |Sub total  | Total
Category |  CAPEX |  OPEX   |           |   CAPEX | OPEX    |           |
1. TP           0       1       1               2       3       5           6
2. MA           0       0       0               0       0       0           0
Total           0       1       1               2       3       5           6
```

**As of 13 Sep 2022**

```
         |      GROUP A     |Sub total  |       GROUP B     |Sub total  | Total
Category |  CAPEX |  OPEX   |           |   CAPEX | OPEX    |           |
1. TP           0       4       4               5       7       12          16
2. MA           0       0       0               0       0       0           0
Total           0       4       4               5       7       12          16
```

They want to see **change from those 2 matrices in %** (increase or decrease).
Something like this

```
         |      GROUP A     |Sub total  |       GROUP B     |Sub total  | Total
Category |  CAPEX |  OPEX   |           |   CAPEX | OPEX    |           |
1. TP           0%    +300%     +300%       +150%   +133%       +140%       +166%
2. MA           0%      0%      0%             0%      0%          0%          0%
Total           0%    +300%     +300%       +150%   +133%       +140%       +166%
```

Is there a way I could do like this on DAX or anything on Power BI?
Please help! Thank you!

---

**Edited: Added sample data**

Here is the data sample I am working on.

| PROJECT_NAME | BUDGET_TYPE | Category | GROUP | Created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAAA | OPEX | 1. TP | A | 12/9/2022 22:07 |
| BBBBBB | CAPEX | 1. TP | A | 11/9/2022 20:57 |
| CCCCC | CAPEX | 1. TP | B | 4/9/2022 14:07 |
| DDDDD | OPEX | 1. TP | B | 5/9/2022 13:57 |
| EEEEEE | CAPEX | 2. MA | A | 9/9/2022 12:22 |
| FFFFFF | OPEX | 1. TP | B | 7/9/2022 9:57 |
| GGGGG | OPEX | 2. MA | B | 16/8/2022 22:08 |
| HHHHH | CAPEX | 1. TP | A | 16/8/2022 22:07 |

Note:

1. I have the dimension tables for `BUDGET_TYPE, Category, GROUP`
2. I have a calendar table whose formula is `CALENDAR = CALENDAR(DATE(2022,1,1), DATE(2022,12,31))`

Comment: you can do it with DAX. You need to add some sample of data table to your question (not as image). Do you have a Calendar table?

Comment: @Mik  Hello! Thank you for being here. I have already added the sample data. And yes, I have a Calendar table